# React Modal component is not working in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-modal

It randomly started doing this and I am not sure why tho. I have two modals (these are named differently) that are exactly the same but only one is working. The modal I am using is the React-Modal library. The first one works just fine on the home page but the second doesn't at all on an edit details page.

What I did notice is that there is a div placed with an Id of __Next on the home page that is working that places the content of the modal inside but that same exact div does not show up on the other page for the same modal to work.

Below are the two components I am working with and its parent component that houses both

Parent:

```js
import styles from './homeheader.module.css';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { useState } from 'react';
import NewInvoice from '../invoice/modal/NewInvoice';
import Link from 'next/link';


import { getDatabase, ref, remove } from "firebase/database";
import { database } from '../firebase/firebase';
import EditInvoice from '../invoice/modal/EditInvoice';





export default function HomeHeader(props) {
    const [newInvoiceModalIsOpen, setNewInvoiceOpen] = useState(false);
    const [editInvoiceModalIsOpen, setEditInvoiceOpen] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();
    const pathName = router.pathname;
    const { data, count, id, detail } = props;


    function openNewInvoiceModalHandler() {
        setNewInvoiceOpen(true)
    }

    function closeNewInvoiceModalHandler() {
        setNewInvoiceOpen(false)
    }
    function openEditInvoiceModalHandler() {
        setEditInvoiceOpen(true)
    }

    function closeEditInvoiceModalHandler() {
        console.log(data)
        setEditInvoiceOpen(false)
    }

    function deleteInvoiceHandler() {
        console.log('delete')
        console.log(id)
        const db = database;
        remove(ref(db, 'invoices/' + id))
    }

    function markAsPaidInvoiceHandler() {
        console.log('paid')
    }


    if (pathName === '/detail/[id]') {
        return (
            <>
                <div className={styles.headerwrapper}>
                    <Link href="/">
                        <a>Go back</a>
                    </Link>
                    {/* <p>{detail.data.status}</p> */}
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={openEditInvoiceModalHandler}>Edit</button>
                        <button onClick={deleteInvoiceHandler}>Delete</button>
                        <button onClick={markAsPaidInvoiceHandler}>Mark as Paid</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <EditInvoice isOpen={editInvoiceModalIsOpen} closeModal={closeEditInvoiceModalHandler} details={detail}/>
            </>
            )
    }



    return (
        <div className={styles.headerwrapper}>
            <div className={styles.leftside}>
                <h1 className={styles.header}>Invoices</h1>
                <p className={styles.text}>There are {count} total invoices</p>
            </div>            
            <div className="right-side">
                <select className={styles.filter} id="filter" placeholder="Filter by status">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                </select>
                <button className={styles.button} onClick={openNewInvoiceModalHandler}>New Invoice</button>
            </div>
            <NewInvoice isOpen={newInvoiceModalIsOpen} closeModal={closeNewInvoiceModalHandler} count={count}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child modal component that IS WORKING:

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
import { database } from '../../firebase/firebase';
import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";

import styles from './newinvoice.module.css'


// ReactModal.setAppElement("#__next")

export default function NewInvoice (props) {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

    function onSubmit(data) {
        const randGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999);
        data.id = randGen;
        const db = database;
        set(ref(db, '/invoices/' + randGen), {
            data: data
        })

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.reload(true)
        }, 500)
        
       
        props.closeModal();
    }


    return (
        <>
            
            <ReactModal isOpen={props.isOpen}>
            <h1>New Invoice</h1>
                <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <label>Street Address</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.street")} />
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.city")} />
                    <label>Postal Code</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.postCode")} />
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.country")} />                    
                    <label>Client&quot;s Name</label>
                    <input {...register("clientName")} />
                    <label>Client&quot;s Email</label>
                    <input {...register("clientEmail")} />
                    <label>Street Address</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.street")} />
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.city")} />
                    <label>Postal Code</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.postCode")} />
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.country")} />
                    <label>Invoice Date</label>
                    <input {...register("createdAt")} />
                    <label>Payment Terms</label>
                    <input {...register("paymentTerms")} />
                    <label>Project Description</label>
                    <input {...register("description")} />                    
                    {/* //Item list goes here */}
                    <input {...register("items")} />

                    <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit"/>
                </form>
                <button onClick={props.closeModal}>Close</button>
            </ReactModal>

        </>
    )
}
```

Child component that is NOT WORKING:

```js
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
import { database } from '../../firebase/firebase';
import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import styles from './newinvoice.module.css'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

ReactModal.setAppElement("#react-modals")

export default function EditInvoice(props) {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState();
    const { isOpen, closeModal, detail } = props;
    const router = useRouter();
    const id = router.query.id;
    const dbLink = `https://invoice-app-3fa85-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/invoices/${id}.json`;

    function onSubmit(data) {
        const db = database;
        set(ref(db, '/invoices/' + id), {
            data: data
        })

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.reload(true)
        }, 500)
        
       
        props.closeModal();
    }


    // function onSubmit(data) {
    //     console.log(data)
    // }

    useEffect(() => {
        // fectchData();
        console.log(formData)
    })

    const fectchData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(dbLink);
            const json = await res.json();

            setFormData(json)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    if (!formData) {
        console.log('not working')
        return <p>Loading....</p>
    }



    return (
        <>
            <ReactModal isOpen={true} portalClassName="editInvoiceModal" parentSelector={() => document.querySelector('#react-modals')}>
            <h1>Edit Invoice </h1>
                <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <label>Street Address</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.street")} defaultValue={detail.senderAddress.street}/>
                 {/*    <label>City</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.city")} defaultValue={formData.senderAddress.city}/>
                    <label>Postal Code</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.postCode")} defaultValue={formData.senderAddress.postCode}/>
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input {...register("senderAddress.country")} defaultValue={formData.senderAddress.country}/>                    
                    <label>Client&quot;s Name</label>
                    <input {...register("clientName")} defaultValue={formData.clientName}/>
                    <label>Client&quot;s Email</label>
                    <input {...register("clientEmail")} defaultValue={formData.clientEmail}/>
                    <label>Street Address</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.street")} defaultValue={formData.clientAddress.street}/>
                    <label>City</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.city")} defaultValue={formData.clientAddress.city}/>
                    <label>Postal Code</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.postCode")} defaultValue={formData.clientAddress.postCode}/>
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <input {...register("clientAddress.country")} defaultValue={formData.clientAddress.country}/>
                    <label>Invoice Date</label>
                    <input {...register("createdAt")} defaultValue={formData.createdAt}/>
                    <label>Payment Terms</label>
                    <input {...register("paymentTerms")} defaultValue={formData.paymentTerms}/>
                    <label>Project Description</label>
                    <input {...register("description")} defaultValue={formData.description}/>                    
                    {/* //Item list goes here */}

                    <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit"/>
                 </form> 
                <button onClick={closeModal}>Close</button>
            </ReactModal>

        </>
    )
}
```

It may be sloppy code as of now and was working to clean it up a lot more until I noticed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent, try adding a placeholder.

```
<div id="react-modals" />
```

Your react modal seems to be looking for a div with the #react-modals id.